# Canonical Landscape - How to increase Cron script timeout?

Tags: cron, landscape

I'm running Canonical Landscape on a new cloud VM.

The service is running fine, except the `update_security_db.sh` script frequently times out, and triggers an alert.

The error is :

```
1 Landscape script has issues: 1 exceeding run timeout.

update_security_db.sh - Running for more than 10 minutes
```

The actual operation of the service is not impacted, and I believe the timeouts occur because it's on a low-power 2GB machine (4GB recommended for Landscape). The script does frequently run successfully through the day, but it also hits the timeout multiple times triggering the alert on the dashboard.

How do I increase the script timeout? I've looked in `/etc/landscape/service.conf` and the Landscape cron file  but can't find any way to allow the offending script to run for longer than 10 minutes.

The log file `/var/log/landscape-service/update-security-db.log` is currently empty.

Answer (score 0):

**First potential solution:** 
Change cron from half-past to let's say 11 or some other random time that works for you.

**Second potential solution:**
Also, you can implement random sleep in the script that will delay executing an actual script.

**Third potential solution:**
Update to latest version of Landscape, I believe that was already implemented (second solution) an resolved in the latest version.

Hope this will help.